# How to append trow to richtextbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I get an Error *`"File Format is not valid"`* when I append RTF to a `richtextbox`

```
        public void Go()
        {
            rtb.Text = "Activated Partial Thromboplastin Time : Collected: 8/17/2012 9:06:00 AM\n";

            rtb.Select(rtb.TextLength, 0);//sets the selection starting point as the end of this Rtb
            rtb.SelectedRtf = @"{\trowd" +//ERROR thrown here
@"\cellx4000" +
@"\cellx9500" +
@"\intbl Activated Partial Thromboplastin Time\cell" +
@"\intbl 34.8 Seconds\cell" +
@"\row}";
}
```

How can I append a `trowd` to my RichTextBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert your rtf code, it has to be a fully independent rtf document, which means you need the `\rtf1{` header and a closing `}` symbol to your text:

```
rtb.SelectedRtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi{\trowd" +//ERROR thrown here
@"\cellx4000" +
@"\cellx9500" +
@"\intbl Activated Partial Thromboplastin Time\cell" +
@"\intbl 34.8 Seconds\cell" +
@"\row}}";
```

Do note the beginning of the string and also the extra `}` bracket at the end.

Comment: So it's impossible to append RTF to Text?  I can only replace the entire contents.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Not sure I follow.  I modified your code to make it work - it inserts the table row at the end of the rtf document.  The SelectedRtf property requires the value to be a valid rtf entity, which requires the `{\rtf1\ansi}` format.  So no, you don't replace the entire contents, just the SelectedRtf part.